# Email configuration in Redmine - undefined method `address='

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, smtp, redmine

I'm not an expert in Ruby and Redmine, but I'm trying to configure email notifications in redmine.
Redmine version 3.4
ruby 2.3.3p222
Phusion Passenger 5.1.7

In configuration.yml I have

```
production:
email_delivery:
delivery_method: :smtp
smtp_settings:
address: "xxxx.pl"
port: 587
authentication: :plain
domain: 'redmine.xxx.pl'
user_name: '.....@redmine.xxx.pl'
password: '......'
```

But I get this error:

```
Error ID: 54731089
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-WqNBmN.html
  Message from application: undefined method `address=' for ActionMailer::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I search little bit and figure out, that I have missing methods in application.rb file.

So in Redmine config/application.rb I add something like that:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              "xxx.pl",
port:                 587,
user_name:            'powiadomienia@redmine.xxx.pl',
password:            '.....',
authentication:       :plain
}
```

but still have the same error. Unfortunately I can't find any examples in Redmine configuration.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You do not need to add your mailer config in `application.rb`. Redmine's `configuration.yml` is enough. The stack trace that belongs to your error message would be helpful in determining where exactly things go wrong.

Comment: Yes, but still have the same error. Even if I use default `application.rb` and configure email in `configuration.yml`, still have the same error and redmine won't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `configuration.yml` is properly indented (use 2 spaces per level of indentation):

```
production:
  email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: 'example.org'
      port: 587
```

The smtp settings (address, port etc) need to be keys in the `smtp_settings` hash. From the error you get I'd say they are keys on the same level as `smtp_settings`, which is wrong.

Comment: Damn, I newer though that space has so matter. Thanks jkraemer. That's solves thing.